# Postgres: Query for list of ids in a mapping table and create If they don't exist

Tags: postgresql

Assume we have the following table whose purpose is to autogenerate a numeric id for distinct (name, location) tuples:

```
CREATE TABLE mapping
(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  location text NOT NULL,
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name_loc on mapping(name location)
```

What is the most  efficient way to query for a set of (name, location) tuples **and** autocreate any mappings that don't already exist, with all mappings (including the ones we created) being returned to the user.

My naive implementation would be something like:

```
SELECT id, name, location 
FROM mappings 
WHERE (name, location) IN ((name_1, location_1)...(name_n, location_n))
```

do something with the results in a programming language of may choice to work out which  results are missing.

```
INSERT 
INTO mappings (name, location) 
VALUES (missing_name_1, missing_loc_1), ... (missing_name_2, missing_loc_2) 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

This gets the job done but I get the feeling there's probably something that can a) be done in pure sql and b) is more efficient.

Comment: (DISTINCT name) CROSS JOIN (DISTINCT location) WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` to get all possible values for the two columns, and `CROSS JOIN` to get their Carthesian product.

`LEFT JOIN` with the original table to get the actual records (if any):

---

```
CREATE TABLE mapping
  ( id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
  , name text NOT NULL
  , location text NOT NULL
 , UNIQUE (name, location)
);

INSERT INTO mapping(name, location) VALUES ('Alice', 'kitchen'), ('Bob', 'bedroom' );

SELECT * FROM mapping;

SELECT n.name, l.location, m.id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name from mapping) n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT location from mapping) l
LEFT JOIN mapping m ON m.name = n.name AND m.location = l.location
        ;
```

---

Results:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
 id | name  | location 
----+-------+----------
  1 | Alice | kitchen
  2 | Bob   | bedroom
(2 rows)

 name  | location | id 
-------+----------+----
 Alice | kitchen  |  1
 Alice | bedroom  |   
 Bob   | kitchen  |   
 Bob   | bedroom  |  2
(4 rows)
```

---

And if you want to physically INSERT the missing combinations:

---

```
INSERT INTO mapping(name, location)
SELECT n.name, l.location
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name from mapping) n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT location from mapping) l
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM mapping m
        WHERE m.name = n.name AND m.location = l.location
        )
        ;

SELECT * FROM mapping;
```

---

```
INSERT 0 2
 id | name  | location 
----+-------+----------
  1 | Alice | kitchen
  2 | Bob   | bedroom
  3 | Alice | bedroom
  4 | Bob   | kitchen
(4 rows)
```